# upload image using paperclip in Rails is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, paperclip

I'm new to rails. I tried to upload an image which is attached to a name. The form is in view name `index` and there's a link to the view named `show`, which will show the name and the image uploaded when adding the name. The controller are `pages`.

I started with a basic form and it worked for adding a `name` field into `Users` model. The problem is when I use paperclip to upload an image while pushing name into database, the image is not showing up in `show`, it's a broken image link instead. Let me explain how I did it.

I installed paperclip.

Add new columns to `Users` model by `rails g paperclip users image` then `rake db:migrate` it and the new columns are in `Users`now.

Next, I create a file_field in the form by `<%= f.file_field :image %>`, and add `has_attached_file :image` to  `Users` model.
Inside `view`, I make a loop of the database to print out the name and the image with `<%= image_tag t.image.url %>`

The name is showed but the image is not, it's missing. Here's the code:

The index view:

```
    <a href="show">To SHOW</a><br>
    <%= form_for @add, :url =>  { :action => "them"}, :html => { :multipart => true} do |f| %>
    Name: <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
    Photo: <%= f.file_field :image %><br>
    <%= f.submit "Add" %>
    <% end %>
```

The show view:

```
    <% @everything.each do |t| %>
     <%= t.name %>
     <%= image_tag t.image.url %>
     <br><br><br>
    <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
    class PagesController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @add = Users.new
      end

      def them
        Users.create :name => params[:users][:name]
        redirect_to :action => "index"
      end

      def show
        @everything = Users.all
      end
    end
```

users.rb model:

```
    class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name

      has_attached_file :image
    end
```

routes.rb:

```
    get "pages/index"
    match "pages/them" => "pages#them", :via => :post
    get "pages/show"
```

I used SQLite Expert Personal to check the database, the name is there but all of the image_ columns (`image_file_name`, `image_content_type`, `image_file_size`, `image_update_at`) are just null.

Did I miss something to get it work? Feel free to ask for more information. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe if you add the photo in the create method, in `them` action, it will be added to the record... You have giving a value to "name"

Comment: I've check some tutorial on the paperclip and found no code to be added to `them` action. What would you suggest me to put in `them` to add the image to the record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Debadatt I found the solution, installing `imagemagick` then apply `Users.create({:name => params[:users][:name], :image => params[:users][:image] })` as Debadatt suggested would do it.

If the error like `Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError:` occurs, just add `gem "cocaine", "= 0.3.2"` into gemfile and `bundle install`, and it would download or update the needed `cocaine`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Users.create({:name => params[:users][:name], :image => params[:users][:image] })
```

Follow rails model declarations and naming conventions.

Users model should be named as User. It will  create a users table after db migration.

Follow the [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions)

Comment: it's not working, the `name` was not even added to the record.

Comment: Can you show me the parameters you are getting in console after submitting the form ?

Comment: Follow rails model declarations and naming conventions.

Comment: This is what showed up in console is this the right thing?

Hold on Im cutting, it's too long

Comment: I am asking about the parameters you are getting after submitting the form, this should be  a hash in console. Check it only

Comment: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"c46E9AOkWehlVnbflHA2tMCO8Jf+M
mcY5g6xd75JxSY=", "users"=>{"name"=>"A", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::Upload
edFile:0x4125288 @original_filename="sm-mabu-165-0599-1.jpg", @content_type="ima
ge/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"users[image]\"; filen
ame=\"sm-mabu-165-0599-1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<Fil
e:C:/Users/NAMHHG~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20141030-9156-l7cn9e>>}, "co
mmit"=>"Thêm"}` this one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63915/discussion-between-debadatt-and-tran-hoai-nam).

Comment: something about error `[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIden
tifiedByImageMagickError: C:/Users/NAMHHG~1/AppData/Local/Temp/sm-mabu-165-0599-
120141030-9156-wztzt3.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using devise for authentication - you will need to go to the application.rb file and add: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller? 

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:update) << :avatar
  end
```